# asp net mvc5 - archivo de recursos para web multi lenguaje

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Estoy intentando hacer mi proyecto multilenguaje para ello he creado la carpeta de asp net "App_LocalResources" y he añadido un archivo de recursos que se denomina "clientes.es-ES.resx"

Luego en las propiedades las he dejado tal como la captura

[image: Captura archivo de recusos]

Ahora voy a la vista y he probado primero hacer un using del namespace "recursos" pero me dice que no existe ese namespace , de hecho cuando escribo @using y quiero autocompletar allí no me sale la palabra "recursos"

También he probado a escribir la ruta entera tal como esto

```
<h2> @testweb.recursos.crearCliente </h2>
```

Pero me dice que no existe la ruta.

Gracias por vuestra ayuda/sugerencias/comentarios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verifica que el acceso sea público:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: muchas gracias , era eso.

Comment: Muchas gracias! :-) Estaba dándole vueltas hasta que llegue aquí